# Install python3-networkx on Debian wheezy

Tags: python, linux, debian, networkx, apt-get

I try to get a script running, which needs python3 and networkx

python3-networkx is not in the apt-repository, so I installed it using:

```
apt-get install python-networkx
```

But still my script crashed saying networkx is not found.

How can I install the python3 version?

Comment: did you mean how to install python 3 version of networkx? which version of python you are using now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For installing packges in Debian, you may run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search networkx
```

Which shows this:

```
python-networkx - tool to create, manipulate and study complex networks
python-networkx-doc - tool to create, manipulate and study complex networks - documentation
python3-networkx - tool to create, manipulate and study complex networks (Python3)
```

Then you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-networkx
```

Alternatively, you can use pip:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install networkx
```

I have tried this in jessie and it worked with python 2.7.

For installing python3 you can use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
```

and for installing networkx:

In Debian jessie:

```
sudo pip3 install networkx
```

In Debian Wheezy:

```
sudo pip-3.2 networkx
```

You can check more info about apt-get [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) or  `man apt-get` in linux terminal.

Also you can check pip documentation [here](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/).

Comment: Since the question was about wheezy, you should add this to your answer: **Use `pip-3.2 install networkx` to use pip3 in Debian wheezy**

Comment: Sorry, I have a jessie so I was not able to test it. I've updated with the, hopefully it helped you solving the problem.